# FF4 profiles portability Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, firefox, migration, firefox-profile

I'd like to move **Firefox 4 profiles** from an old Windows box to Linux and see all the profile data I had on Windows (bookmarks, passwords and everything) on the new workstation. I can't figure out myself if copying the profile folder "as is" to the new location (Linux) is the right way to do this data migration.

I found [this article](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) and [this](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Backing%20up%20your%20information), but it is not specified if profile portability is guaranted between different platforms or not.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firefox-sync/).

> Free browser add-on that lets you stay
>   in sync with your Firefox. Access your
>   history, passwords, bookmarks and even
>   open tabs across all your devices.

Comment: I don't have to sync a computer and a mobile phone.

Comment: It will sync all your computers too

Comment: @Guandalino see my edit, it's included with FF4.  It's not explicitly for phone/computer it's for computer/computer.

Comment: I went to go check yours out so I was reading the description... I had forgotten they were going to include that now!  Well, that product includes history info so yours is probably the best option.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the profile data is based on text files anyway, the only issue would be the history sqlite database, which *might* not be Linux compatible, though I would expect it to be.

Update: I dug a little bit deeper, and found out that there *will* be discrepancies regarding the following profile items:

- compatibility.ini : not so serious, but some compatibility information will be lost. Can be easily modified to adjust directory/path names.
- extensions.ini : Because you have absolute paths to your extensions in this file, you will probably lose track of all your extensions/addons if you carry this 1/1 over to your linux user directory.
  Nothing that can't be fixed with a simple search&replace, though.
- prefs.js: There are a couple of entries here like *browser.download.dir*,  *browser.download.lastDir* or *dwhelper.storagedirectory* which can be re-set easily once on linux.
- search.json:  Almost all search plugin meta contains absolute path names. Again, nothing disastrous. Like the extensions.ini, you can S&R.

The rest of it are either binary files or sqlite databases which can safely be transported to your linux dir, or meta text files that contain no OS-specific detail.

Comment: So are you saying there won't be Windows/Linux path compatibility issues?

Comment: @Guandalino check out the updated answer.

Comment: already done (and upvoted).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't keep track of history (I don't believe), and you have to sign in, but [XMarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/) will allow you to synchronize between the two.

**Edit:** There's no need, FF4 includes the Sync feature (proposed by Simon in his answer) with it now
[image]